# error in looping

Tags: c++, stream

consider this code snippet

```
   void make(int n)
   {
     std::string user_input;
     std::istringstream iss(user_input);
     char letter;
     int index;
     while(n>0)
    { cout<<n<<endl;
      std::getline(std::cin, user_input);
      while (iss >> letter >> index)
      cout<<letter<<' '<<index;
      n--;
    }
   }  
   int main()
   { int n;
     cin>>n;
     make(n);
     return 0; 
   }
```

here loop is not running correctly
if i put n=5 then output is

5
//getline doesn't work
4
then getline works... why this

Comment: What do you mean "getline doesn't work"?

Comment: @ Gordon Bailey: i mean that for n=5 nothing happens . only one statement is executing in loop body i.e.     n-- .When n becomes 4 ,everthing is ok..

Comment: What is this bizarre indentation scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's doing this, is because when you're calling `getline()`, it's taking what's in `cin` and putting it in the variable.  However, when you initially called `cin` to take in the inital input, the newline character remained in the buffer after going into your `make()` function.

So when you enter the loop, the first `getline()` takes `'\n'` from `cin`, and the buffer was cleared.  That's why it seems to "skip" the first iteration as it would seem.

So in order to get it to function correctly, you should clear your input buffer when you call your function using `cin.ignore()`, like so:

```
 void make(int n)
 {
 cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); //ignores 1000 characters or until sees \n
 std::string user_input;
 std::istringstream iss(user_input);
 char letter;
 int index;
 while(n>0)
{ cout<<n<<endl;
  std::getline(std::cin, user_input);
  while (iss >> letter >> index)
  cout<<letter<<' '<<index;
  n--;
}
}  
int main()
{ int n;
  cin>>n;
  make(n);
  return 0; 
 }
```

I haven't used c++ much recently, so at the moment, i'm not sure if there's a better way to handle this, but this should give you a good direction.

Comment: Almost; it's the `\n` from the `n` input that's still in the buffer.

Comment: Oh, so value put in is gone, but only the \n stayed behind?
Edit: I edited it, thanks.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Yeah, i realized after i thought about it when you mentioned it haha, I just assumed the whole thing stayed behind since I knew something was there.